# Hibernate configure file

Tags: java, hibernate

Let say I have the follow code.

```
private static String configFile = null;


   File cf = new File(configFile);
   Configuration c = new Configuration();
    if (cf.exists() && cf.isFile()) {
            c.configure(cf);
        } else {
            c.configure(configFile);
    }
```

I am wondering what is the difference between `c.configure(cf)` and `c.configure(configFile)`. In my code,configFile is repsented as resource and cf is the the configFile object.

I found these two from this ([api](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#configure(java.io.File))).

```
public Configuration configure(String resource)
                        throws HibernateException

public Configuration configure(File configFile)
                        throws HibernateException
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the API isn't explicitly clear, is it?

I tracked it as far as this class before getting fed up:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/cfgxml/internal/ConfigLoader.java

But it looks like in case of configure(String resource), it is the name of a resource as would be passed to the Java class loader to get a resource as a stream, i.e.:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Whereas, configure(File configFile), it uses a FileInputStream.

In either case Hibernate is still expecting the same XML format for the configuration.